# Search for a JPG on my computer by using a smaller JPG?

Tags: windows-7, windows, search, jpeg

I have a low resolution image that I know I have the full resolution image stored somewhere on my computer. Is there anyway to search for a JPG on my computer by using a small resolution of an image as an input to search for?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**TL;DR: Use Visipics.**

---

What you're looking for is called *[reverse image search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_image_search)*:

> [It's a] technique that involves providing a sample image
>   that [the system] will then base its search upon; in terms of information
>   retrieval, the sample image is what formulates a search query.

The most popular reverse image searches are web-based, like [TinEye](https://www.tineye.com/), and even [Google Image Search](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1325808?p=ws_images_searchbyimagetooltip&rd=1).

Those, however, will search among images present on the web; what you need is a tool that will perform reverse image search against the files on your computer.

Well, [Visipics](http://www.visipics.info) does exactly what you need, is free, runs on Windows (2000, 2003, XP, Vista, Seven), and Linux (via Wine). I have used it myself in the past and it is really fast, supports JPG, PNG and RAW, and can have its sensitivity filter  customized manually.

From the official site:

> VisiPics does more than just look for identical files, it goes beyond
>   checksums to look for similar pictures and (...) applies five image
>   comparison filters in order to measure how close pairs of images on
>   the hard drive are.
>
> Visipic is considerably faster than any other
>   commercial product and (...) will
>   detect two different resolution files of the same picture as a
>   duplicate, or the same picture saved in different formats, or
>   duplicates where only minor cosmetic changes have taken place.

[image: visipics]

Comment: More good news, from the Visipics download page: "VisiPics has been tested successfully with Wine on Linux"

Comment: This is perfect - THANK YOU exactly what I was looking to do! Happy New Year!

Comment: For me, VisiPics wasn't as good as: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14094/is-there-a-free-visual-similarity-image-local-hard-drive-search#comment176859_30477